# What happens to the address stored in a pointer when the content in that address is swapped out and back?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory-management, paging

Say a pointer is pointing at an object at some address.

Later, because there is not enough memory, the OS swaps some pages out of the memory and the object is in one of the page and the pointer is not.

Then, the page that has the object is swapped in later to a different location in memory.

What happens to the address stored in the pointer? Does the address get updated to the new address where the object is residing?

Or is there something that I am misunderstanding in how the memory management works?

Comment: What is the programming problem you're having? Are you seeing pointers getting corrupted after being swapped out? Please elaborate on the scenario and the details of your operating system. (Maybe you didn't manage the page lock properly.)

Comment: The basic thing that you are misunderstanding is that pointer in your program is pointing to a *virtual* address.  The memory management system may translate this to different *physical* addresses over time, but from the program's point of view it is always the same address.

Comment: I just came up with this question when I was coding something thats unrelated to this question. So there is no programming problem I have, Raymond.

I see, thank you, Eamonn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The address is a an address to virtual memory in the first place. So the address does not need to change – the OS will make sure that the next time you access memory under that address, the address is mapped to the correct physical address.